# Oracle: ORA-01089: immediate shutdown in progress - no operations are permitted

Tags: oracle-database

I have Oracle XE 10.0.2 installed on my development system.

Recently I have been unable to restart it:

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/oracle-xe stop
Shutting down Oracle Database 10g Express Edition Instance.
Stopping Oracle Net Listener.

$ sudo /etc/init.d/oracle-xe start
Starting Oracle Net Listener.
Starting Oracle Database 10g Express Edition Instance.

$ sqlplus 

SQL*Plus: Release 10.2.0.1.0 - Production on Tue Feb 4 19:54:53 2014

Copyright (c) 1982, 2005, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Enter user-name: hr
Enter password: 
ERROR:
ORA-01089: immediate shutdown in progress - no operations are permitted
```

So I tried killing off all oracle processes by hand:

```
$ sudo killall oracle tnslsnr
```

This kills the processes (they are no longer listed in `ps`). I then try starting Oracle again:

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/oracle-xe start
Starting Oracle Net Listener.
Starting Oracle Database 10g Express Edition Instance.
```

SQL*Plus gives the same error.

/usr/lib/oracle/xe/app/oracle/admin/XE/bdump/alert_XE.log says:

```
Starting Oracle Database 10g Express Edition Instance.
Tue Feb  4 19:59:30 2014
Starting ORACLE instance (normal)
```

I have not reconfigured Oracle recently, but I have shut it down hard (power off), so it may be in a inconsistent state that I need to force it to recover from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A complete guide on how to get Oracle on GNU/Linux unstuck from ORA-01089 is [here](http://oletange.blogspot.dk/2014/02/ora-01089-immediate-shutdown-in.html).

The idea is basically to log in to Oracle as sysdba and issue a shutdown command (oracle user in OS is the standard in this example from the link provided):

```
root# sudo su - oracle
oracle$ sqlplus
SQL*Plus: Release 10.2.0.1.0 - Production on Sun Feb 9 15:16:09 2014
Copyright (c) 1982, 2005, Oracle.  All rights reserved.
Enter user-name: / as sysdba
Connected to:
Oracle Database 10g Express Edition Release 10.2.0.1.0 - Production
SQL> shutdown abort
ORACLE instance shut down.
```

In a single line:

```
echo shutdown abort | sudo su - oracle -c "sqlplus / as sysdba"
```

If this does not work try some of the spells on https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/15888/oracle-shutdown-method and finish up with:

```
/etc/init.d/oracle-xe stop
/etc/init.d/oracle-xe start
```

Comment: Would you consider improving your question by providing answer in your post? You basically gave link. If it dies, the answer is lost.

Answer (score 0):

If sending a simple `TERM` signal does not kill a process (`kill` by default, sends a process a `TERM` signal, which is a way of politely asking a process to close and save data and/or files in use and end), one can then send a `KILL` signal to a process, e.g.:

```
sudo killall -9 oracle tnslsnr
```

Only do this after sending the process a `TERM` signal and giving it a reasonable about of time to close things down (it could possibly corrupt databases and what not, but if it's been 10 minutes, maybe the program has just hung)

---

OK, a quick Google search of `ORA-01989` shows the following discussion:

https://community.oracle.com/thread/2523811?tstart=0

Where someone points out that:

`ORA-01089: immediate shutdown in progress - no operations are permitted --> happends when you connect to database with a current user, not as sysdba.`

And they say this error can be fixed by logging in to the database as the `sysdba` account and either shutting down or bringing up the Oracle database.

(No, I have never administered an Oracle database.  But my experience with error codes is the best way to get help from the all-knowing Google is by Googling the exact error code or message)

Comment: The processes die (i.e. `ps` does not see neither oracle nor tnslsnr anymore), so the processes are not hung.

Comment: I have updated my answer